# Inherit assignment from parent class in Fortran

Tags: oop, fortran, assignment-operator

Sorry, me again!

Even though I'm getting better with OOP in Fortran (which is probably the craziest thing I've ever worked with), I have difficulties with inheritance. Unfortunately I do not understand the syntax which allows me to do that.

Basically, what I want to do is override the assignment operator `=` which allows me to return any *primitive type*. A basic example with only one primitive type *(real)* would look like this:

```
module overload

    implicit none

    public func, assignment(=)

    interface assignment(=)
        module procedure equalAssignmentReal
        !! additional procedures for integer, character, logical if neccessary
    end interface

contains

    subroutine equalAssignmentReal(lhs, rhs)      !! <-- all these subroutines should be in the parent class

        implicit none

        real,     intent(out) :: lhs
        class(*), intent(in)  :: rhs

        select type(rhs)
            type is (real)
                lhs = rhs
        end select

        return

    end subroutine equalAssignmentReal

    function func(string) result(res)      !! <-- I want this function in the child class

        implicit none

        character(len=*), intent(in) :: string
        class(*), allocatable        :: res

        if (  string == "real" ) allocate(res, source=1.0)

        return

    end function func

end module overload

program test

    use overload

    implicit none

    real :: var

    var = func('real')

    print *, "var = ", var

end program test
```

This works when compiling with *GNU Fortran* (not with Intel as they permit intrinsic assignment overloading). So my question is now how would I define a **parent class** in a separate module which contains all the assignment overloads (real, integer, character, logical) and use this overrides in a **child class** which only contains `func`? In the program I only want to include the child class and assign the value with something like:

```
type(child_class) :: child
real :: var

var = child%func('real')
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand what the role of the parent or child type is in this arrangement. Type bound assignment has to involve the bound type, either on the left hand side or the right hand side of the assignment.  In your last example block, the left hand side is of type real, the right hand side is unlimited polymorphic (~no type).

Comment: You use the word "override".  Did you mean "overload"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As no one seems to know the answer and I have no clue how to work it out with **types** I post this "workaround" here in case someone has the same problem. I simply put the assignment overload into a separate module and *use* the module wherever I need it. A simplified example looks like this:

```
module overload

    implicit none

    public assignment(=)

    interface assignment(=)
        module procedure equalAssignmentReal
        module procedure equalAssignmentInteger
        !! additional procedures for character, logical if neccessary
    end interface

contains

    subroutine equalAssignmentReal(lhs, rhs)

        implicit none

        real,     intent(out) :: lhs
        class(*), intent(in)  :: rhs

        select type(rhs)
            type is (real)
                lhs = rhs
        end select

        return

    end subroutine equalAssignmentReal

    subroutine equalAssignmentInteger(lhs, rhs)

        implicit none

        integer,  intent(out) :: lhs
        class(*), intent(in)  :: rhs

        select type(rhs)
            type is (integer)
                lhs = rhs
        end select

        return

    end subroutine equalAssignmentInteger

end module overload


module assignment

    implicit none

    public find
    public par1

    real    :: par1
    integer :: par2

contains

    subroutine init

        use overload

        implicit none


        par1 = find('real')
        par2 = find('integer')        

        return

    end subroutine init

    function find(in) result(out)

        implicit none

        character(len=*), intent(in)  :: in
        class(*), allocatable         :: out

        if ( in == 'real' ) then

            allocate(out, source=1.)

        else if ( in == 'integer' ) then

            allocate(out, source=2)

        end if 

        return

    end function find

end module assignment

program test

    use assignment

    implicit none

    call init

    print *, "par1 = ", par1
    print *, "par2 = ", par2

end program test
```

I use this to extract parameters of unknown primitive type from a file (json).